Why is Xenon-135 so good at capturing or absorbing neutrons ('poison') despite already having such an abundance of neutrons?
I would assume that, having an odd number of neutrons, it wants to absorb one more and then emit an alpha particle.... but the most common decay product is apparently Cesium-135, so....
I read that Xenon-135 is only so effective at capturing neutrons traveling at 'thermal' energies, but I still don't understand why it would be able to absorb a neutron of any energy.....

Xenon 135 has 81 neutrons. This is one less than the magic number of 82 neutrons that form a closed shell.
As a result, it is energetically extremely favourable for Xenon 135 to capture a neutron.
